# can we send and array in BasicNameValuePair

Tags: java, apache, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to send an array through BasicNameValePair in java. Is it possible and if yes how.

String [] Parameters = {"19"};
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ids",Parameters[]));

I need to send parameter string array.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried this? if i understand you  question correctly.

```
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(String.format("user[%d]", i), Parameters .toString()));
```

Comment: I tried toString() method. But I want to send array as it is.